# Postgres CIDR. How to select only network w/o subnet?

Tags: postgresql, networking, cidr

I have a table Net where is the list of networks

-- Table: net

```
CREATE TABLE net
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  cidr cidr,
  description text,
  CONSTRAINT net_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

I need to select all the networks that do not. belong to other networks. ie only network without subnets. How to build a query?

cidr:
10.0.0.0/8
10.1.0.0/16
10.2.0.0/16
10.3.0.0/16
10.3.1.0/24
10.3.2.0/24
10.3.3.0/24
10.15.1.0/24
10.15.2.0/24
10.15.3.0/24
172.20.0.0/16
172.21.0.0/16
172.0.0.0/8
11.11.11.0/24
Top rated net is 10.0.0.0/8, 172.0.0.0/8, 11.11.11.0/24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your question like this:
You want all network specifications that are not contained in any other network specification, i.e. are not part of the subnet of another.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   net
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT cidr FROM net n WHERE n.cidr >> net.cidr);
```

Produces your expected result.
Have a look at the chapter [Network Address Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-net.html) in the manual for more on the `>>` operator.
Semi-join with `NOT EXISTS` is probably the fastest way to do this.

Comment: Why the not exists rather than a left join where condition = null?

Comment: In most simple cases, both query styles result in the same query plan. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860